# z-Index on mobile site

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I'm trying to design the mobile view of a personal website for myself. 
The menu should drop down using jQuery. So the following code works perfect on Firefox, but unfortunately not on the Safari Browser of my iPhone. I have already tried several solution approaches and read many postings on the internet, but none worked. 
Here's my the body of the page:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <aside>
        <img src="images/avatar.png" class="avatar"/>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="home" class="active"><a onclick="view_page('home'); return false;">Home</a></li>
                <li id="projects"><a onclick="view_page('projects'); return false;">Projects</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a onclick="view_page('contact'); return false;">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="dropdown"><img src="images/arrow.png" /></a>
    </aside>
    <main>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>About me.</h2>
            <p id="justify">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </p>
        </div>
    </main>
```

And here the relevant part of the mobile CSS section:

```
aside nav{
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 30;
    width: 100%;
}
main{
    margin-top: 4.1em;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

When I open the complete page in the browser, the menu should be brought to the front using `z-index`. But it is displayed in the background. What am I doing wrong (likely with `z-index`)?

Comment: Add CSS part for `<aside>` and add example on http://jsfiddle.net or link on your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `position: relative` and `z-index` on `aside nav`, move`z-index: 30` to `aside`. Something like this:

```
aside {
    ...
    z-index: 30;
}

aside nav {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

main {
    margin-top: 4.1em;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Read about `z-index` works — http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/.